# How do I use junk?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm pretty new to this game and probably missing something really obvious, but I can't figure out how to use junk.
That microscope would probably be useful in the medical bay, for example.
What do I press to make it go?

[image: junk]

Comment: There's an [additional answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267075/108003), with links, on a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Junk is used for crafting, using two new rooms: the Weapon Workshop and the Outfit Workshop.

Once you have found some recipes, and built/upgraded a sufficient level workshop, you can assign dwellers to the room, then access the "craft" button when the occupied room is selected.

Comment: Also, you can scrap weapons and armor into junk from the storage screen.

Comment: Indeed, but that's getting junk, not using it.

Comment: Well, you need to get it in order to use it. I've found that some of the supposedly common junk items aren't found in the wasteland very often, but are easily obtained by scrapping.